# Comment rendre l'anglais "over-under achiever"?

Tags: traduction, anglais

L'expression anglaise "over-under achiever" désigne par exemple un étudiant qui, bien qu'ayant déjà une moyenne suffisante pour passer en classe supérieure, produit un travail supplémentaire, mais en le faisant par dessus la jambe. Je ne pense pas qu'il existe une expression aussi condensée en français mais j'essaie de trouver une tournure élégante et aussi succincte que possible.

Comment: Quel concept étrange ! À quoi ça sert ?

Comment: Je ne les trouve nulle part (c’est a dire qu’ils ne sont pas “idiomatique” [hence the comment]) mais comme synonymes assez proches de "over-under achiever" en anglais il y a (d’après moi) “a/n mediocre/under-performing/under-achieving perfectionist "  qui **peut-être** pourraient être traduits comme «une perfectionniste moyenne/médiocre/sous-performante». …. (En anglais, il y a aussi “an imperfect perfectionist” [from which you could get "une perfectionniste imparfaite," which does have a few google hits], mais je ne le trouve pas [in either language] aussi proche que les autres.)

Comment: un etudiant "qui ne se foule pas"?

Comment: _Sur-sous doué_ haha. Mais l'échelle de temps ou la fréquence n'est pas la même parce que si quelqu'un se plantait plus souvent qu'il ne réussissait, comment pourrait-on prétendre qu'il est surdoué (en contexte académique) ? C'est quand il fait des trucs pour la forme qu'il échoue. Merci !

Comment: Effectivement Google ne trouve presqu'aucune référence dans le monde anglophone. Je dois être tombé sur des américains un peu bizarres! Merci pour les suggestions en tout cas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brillant élève d'opérette.

La seule référence à "over-under achiever" que j'ai trouvée sur Internet est le Urban Dictionary (source non officielle souvent non vérifiée). Il est donc probable que ce terme en Anglais soit un néologisme, il est donc approprié de le traduire par un autre néologisme.

"overachiever", lui, existe bel et bien et est généralement traduit par "élève brillant".

En français on pourrait par exemple rajouter le complément "du dimanche", qui donne un effet ridiculisant (comme la version anglaise). Par contre on perd beaucoup de précision. "d'opérette" sert le même but de ridicule mais est davantage relié au fait de mettre l'accent sur les apparences et délaisser la qualité.

Comment: Belle créativité! Bravo!